# Why am I getting run time error for the following code when I submit on an online judge?

Tags: java

Here is my input code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main1 {

   public static void main (String args[]) {

       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
           while (true)    {
           int n = input.nextInt();
           if (n != 2 && n != 4 && n != 6 && n != 8)
              break;
          else    {
               if (n == 2)    {
                   System.out.println ("00\n01\n81");
               }
               else if (n == 4)   {
                   System.out.println ("0000\n0001\n2025\n3025\n9801");
               }
               else if (n == 6)   {
                   System.out.println ("000000\n000001\n088209\n494209\n998001");
               }
               else if (n == 8)   {
                   System.out.println ("00000000\n00000001\n04941729\n07441984\n24502500\n25502500\n52881984\n60481729\n99980001");
               }
               else    {
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: My magic ball saying that there is an error in your code

Comment: Maybe the online judge thinks you need to fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling nextInt()  without checking that there is an int to read.

Probably that online test feeds non numbers to your program.

You should call hasNextInt() before.